# How to solve "python pip install sslkeylog" error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Tags: python, pip

I try to install sslkeylog module however got the error as follows.

I installed visual studio "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" as suggested in the error message however couldn't solved the problem.

I will appreciate if you can guide me how to solve this problem.

```
pip install sslkeylog

Collecting sslkeylog
  Using cached sslkeylog-0.4.0.tar.gz (4.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: sslkeylog
  Building wheel for sslkeylog (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      copying sslkeylog.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      running build_ext
      building '_sslkeylog' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sslkeylog
  Running setup.py clean for sslkeylog
Failed to build sslkeylog
Installing collected packages: sslkeylog
  Running setup.py install for sslkeylog ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for sslkeylog did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      running install
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      copying sslkeylog.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      running build_ext
      building '_sslkeylog' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> sslkeylog

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Visual Studio Build Tools for C++

[download link here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&channel=Release&version=VS2022&source=VSLandingPage&cid=2030&passive=false)

[page link here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)

This will download the installer, open it and select `Community` on the `Available` tab. Then select Desktop Development with C++ and install that

[image: Desktop Development with C++]

iirc that should solve your issue ツ

Comment: I had installed modules from "Individual components" tab but didn't installed the "Desktop Development with C++" which you highlighted above. After installing this module from "Workloads" tab it solved my problem. Thanks for your support..